# Replace parent component entirely in child route

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, nested-routes

I'm trying to nest routes with the VueJS router (next/4.x) so that the child route completely replaces the parent component.

The example given [here](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html#nested-routes) assumes that for each sub route, there's a sub component being rendered, but I'd like to replace the component `User` entirely when navigating to `/user/johnny/profile` instead of rendering `Profile` within the `User` component.

```
/user/johnny/profile                     /user/johnny/posts
+------------------+                  +-----------------+
| User             |                  | User            |
| +--------------+ |                  | +-------------+ |
| | Profile      | |  +------------>  | | Posts       | |
| |              | |                  | |             | |
| +--------------+ |                  | +-------------+ |
+------------------+                  +-----------------+
```

I tried to omit the `<router-view>` tag in `User`, but that just doesn't render `Profile` when navigating to `/user/johnny/profile` (most likely because it doesn't find a place to render the `Profile` component).

The only thing that seems to be working is to check the route name in UserComponent and hide `<router-view>` when the route is `/user/johnny` or hide the markup for UserComponent and just show `<router-view` when the child route is active. I wonder if there's a better way to do this. For instance, it would be nice if the `<router-view>` could just be removed and the ProfileComponents finds the next closest parent's `<router-view>` to render itself, but I haven't found ways to configure this or examples that would suggest that's possible...

Answer (score 0):

What you need to is to create both the Profile and Posts components as childlren routes to user's route.

So, in the user's component, you only need to define the  in the template's tag.

Example:

route.js

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/user',
    name: 'user',
    component: UserComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '/profile',
        name: 'user-profile',
        component: UserProfileComponent
      },
      {
        path: '/post',
        name: 'user-post',
        component: UserPostComponent
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

UserComponent.vue

```
<template>
  <router-view />
</template>
```